# Installing Cuda-Python in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, python, cuda

My `nvidia-smi`

```
(cython) nyck33@nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6:~/Documents/cuda-start-dec2022/cuda-python/examples/0_Introduction$ nvidia-smi
Sun Dec  4 23:38:29 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.86.01    Driver Version: 515.86.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8     2W /  N/A |    810MiB /  4096MiB |     13%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1888      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                299MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2155      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              209MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3336      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       49MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3622      G   ...4/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      160MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12214      G   ...049194704206746220,131072       34MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     47977      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       53MiB |
```

then

```
cuda-python/examples/0_Introduction$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
```

I can use Cuda and debug for `.cu` files.

Following instructions here:  https://nvidia.github.io/cuda-python/install.html#installing-from-pypi

I did `pip install cuda-python` which gave me:

```
cuda-python               11.8.1                   pypi_0    pypi
```

On that page it says, "match the major-minor" so do I need 11.7?

If so, how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the 11.7 from the Nvidia link https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-7-0-download-archive

Comment: what I ended up doing was `pip uninstall cuda-python` then `pip install cuda-python==11.7` which seemed to work as I can run the Cuda Numba examples.